# How to add JS in react

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I need to add JavaScript code in react, can anyone help me with this, I'm new to coding so please guide me exactly how to add JS in this react, I'm attaching code here please tell me how and where to add JavaScript code in here

Slider.js

```
<div className="slide-container">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="clash-card barbarian">
          <div className="clash-card__image clash-card__image--barbarian">
            <img
              src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/195612/barbarian.png"
              alt="barbarian"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="clash-card__level clash-card__level--barbarian">
            Level 4
          </div>
          <div className="clash-card__unit-name">The Barbarian</div>
          <div className="clash-card__unit-description">
            The Barbarian is a kilt-clad Scottish warrior with an angry,
            battle-ready expression, hungry for destruction. He has Killer
            yellow horseshoe mustache.
          </div>

          <div className="clash-card__unit-stats clash-card__unit-stats--barbarian clearfix">
            <div className="one-third">
              <div className="stat">
                20<sup>S</sup>
              </div>
              <div className="stat-value">Training</div>
            </div>

            <div className="one-third">
              <div className="stat">16</div>
              <div className="stat-value">Speed</div>
            </div>

            <div className="one-third no-border">
              <div className="stat">150</div>
              <div className="stat-value">Cost</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is JavaScript code which I have to add in this react app, To move carousal of slides

```
(function() {
  
    var slideContainer = $('.slide-container');
    
    slideContainer.slick();
    
    $('.clash-card__image img').hide();
    $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeIn(200);
    
    // On before slide change
    slideContainer.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeOut(1000);
    });
    
    // On after slide change
    slideContainer.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeIn(200);
    });
    
})();
```

I have tried but I unable to run the code, So please guide me where to add this JavaScript code in react (Slider.js) file to move the carousal.

Comment: jQuery and React don't mix well, I would strongly suggest not combining them.

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM like that in a React app.

Comment: Have you seen https://react-slick.neostack.com?

Answer (score 0):

I should suggest you to read and learn at [React documentation website](https://reactjs.org/), for the best result.

But yeah, sometimes there was alternative ways that we can take. Like Udemy, and etc.

According to the Docs, React was only javascript. But we still can use HTML on it, on the `return` area.

Sample:

```js
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

root.render(<HelloMessage name="Taylor" />);
```

Hope it was helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this package instead of trying to implement original Slick slider library to React.
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick